# Why the rate is part of the exponent on continuous compounding formula?

Tags: exponentiation, subgroup-growth

Could someone explain how the rate  is part of the exponent on the continuous compounding formula

$A= p e^{rt}$

while that is not the case in the simple compound interest formula?

$A= p (1+\frac{r}{n})^{ nt}$

Thank you.

Comment: The limit as $n \to \infty$ of $(1+\frac xn)^n$ is $e^x$.

Comment: I’m fine with the limit how we arrived to ‘e’ , what  I couldn’t understand is how come the rate end up being in the exponent

Comment: Examine their comment more closely. In your case $x$ is $r$.

Comment: Intuition: The derivative of $(1+\frac xn)^n$ is $(1+\frac xn)^{n-1}$ and the limit of that is the same as that of $(1+\frac xn)^n\,.$ In other words: the limit of $(1+\frac xn)^n$ behaves like $e^x\,.$

Comment: Note that $(1+\frac xn)^n = (1+\frac 1{\frac nx})^{\frac nx})^x$.

Comment: Waw! It all came together now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Upon taking the logarithm in your 2nd equation yields $\ln(A) = \ln(p) + n t \ln(1+r/n)$. In the limit of $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\ln(1+r/n)$ tends to $r/n$. Hence $\ln(A) \rightarrow \ln(p) + r t$ which is your 1st equation.